# How to remove TIME END from datetime in php

Tags: php, html, datetime

I currently have this below:

9:00 am - 5:00 pm

I would like it to only show the start time:

9:00 am

This is the code I have:

```
             <td class="time event-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php espresso_event_date_range( 'g:i a', ' ', ' ', ' ', $event->ID() ); ?></td>
```

Comment: You could always just explode the value using `explode` then echoing the first cll.

Comment: the smart solution is to edit espresso_event_date_range NOT edit its output

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$exp_date = explode("-",espresso_event_date_range( 'g:i a', ' ', ' ', ' ', $event->ID() ));

<td class="time event-<?php echo $post->ID." ".$exp_date[0]; ?>"></td>
```